# How to extract/copy string from text to DOS batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, copy, dos

I have a text file `output.txt` with contents below:

```
**Adapter #0
Enclosure Device ID: 10
Slot Number: 16
Enclusure Device ID: 10
Slot Number: 15**
```

How can copy value "10" from Enclosure Device ID to command below which is part of my batch file (mark in xx)?

```
c:\megacli\megacli -CfgLdAdd -r1 [**xx**:0,**xx**:1] -a0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for /f "tokens=6 delims=#: " %x in (output.txt) do echo %x
```

When using in a batchfile use double `%` signes (aka `%%x`)

Comment: The question's original formatting probably mislead you. As you can now see, the `tokens` option should probably be `4` (if I understood your intention correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Bah, your silly edit changes everything.  Here you go again.

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%I in ('find "Enclosure" output.txt') do (
    c:\megacli\megacli -CfgLdAdd -r1 [%%I:0,%%I:1] -a0
)
```